# is it a security concern to run web and app containers in the same namespace in OpenShift?

Tags: containers, openshift, devops

What will be the issue by running web containers and app containers in a same namespace in OpenShift? Is it a security no-no or to just keep and web and app layers separately?

IMO, OpenShift is pretty secure and running both web and app containers in the same namespace should not be a concern. But how others are viewing this?

What are the pros and cons? What is the best practice?

Comment: Namespaces are a way to have a logical group of applications...in any way. Maybe you are a software factory and you have multiple SaaS systems....then you can have you namespaces of projects, named after every one of you apps......or maybe you want to group for tennant, or by app type, like frontends apps and backend apps....there is no silver bullet, just the way that makes sense to you should be the right one 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespaces don't really provide any significant security benefits. Most of the security rules and policies you can enforce, such as  [NetworkPolicies](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/networking/network_policy/creating-network-policy.html), can just as easily be built with selectors as with namespaces. I'm sure there are some extreme edge advantages to having separate namespaces, but I don't see it as a common factor in making the decision.

As Hackerman mentions, namespaces are about logical grouping. (And, well, namespaces, so that you don't have name collisions.)

And this isn't because "OpenShift is pretty secure". If there is some security fault with the container, there is still a security fault with the container. And there are many tools available to you in OpenShift and OpenShift Advanced Container Security to help you mitigate those faults. But namespaces aren't really one of them.

Comment: Thanks David and Hackerman for your inputs. We are continuing with a hardened Nginx image and trying the container along with other app services.